JOptionPane icons with Windows L&F are not the Windows 10 ones
I want JOptionPane dialog boxes to use the Windows 10 icons, but it uses Windows 7 ones.
Here is my code:
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOPtest {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {

            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test", "Test", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

    }

}

This gives me the following message box with the wrong icon on Windows 10:

I would rather have this message box with the right icon (from system error message):


And what I can put on that argument to match the wanted result?

Windows icons locations. Where are the default icons found?  Once you find the icons, you use the JOptionPane constructor that allows you to specify the icons.  See How to Make Dialogs for exsmples.

And how can I get them into a icon?

Read an image into an Image instance using ImageIO and then an ImageIcon instance.

can you give me some example code to read icons from dll files?

Parsing a .dll file is not an easy task.  Are you sure your users will care if the icon is slightly different?  And out of curiosity, what version of Java are you using?

How do you get the icons out of shell32.dll?

I only code for personal use, but it make me get nervous. I use OpenJDK 21 Eclipse Termurin builf

It seems Java is using the icons obtained from System.Drawing.SystemIcons, which are the old ones you see.
I’m not a .Net expert, but if I understand correctly, this proposal will add a new API, GetStockIcon, that returns modern icons.  (It appears there is no StockIconId for the “question” dialog icon.  A design oversight perhaps?)
Until that version of .Net is publicly released and available on standard, fully up-to-date consumer Windows installations, all you can do is scour existing .dll files for the icons.  Parsing a .dll file manually is possible but is not easy.  Search for documentation on the format.
While having an eye for detail is important for a software engineer, end users may not care nearly as much.  It is entirely possible that most of your end users have never noticed the difference between the old and new dialog icons, and don’t care that Java uses the older ones.  It may not be worth the effort to extract and show the newest ones.

Shit, I am going to extract them and use one or other depending of the Windows version
